# Bundle в Bundle

Tags: android

Можно ли положить Bundle в Bundle?

Answer (score 1):

Да, можно. Метод putBundle(string argsName,bundle) поможет.

```
Bundle b1=new Bundle();
Bundle b2=new Bundle();
b1.putBundle("bundle",b2);
```

Answer (score 1):

В Bundle можно класть объекты классов, которые реализуют интерфейс `Parcelable`, как например и сам класс [Bundle](http://developer.android.com/intl/ru/reference/android/os/Bundle.html). Следовательно ответ - да, можно